# What computer resources are used for audio processing?

Tags: audio, resources, audio-processing

[image][image]**Environment description:**

1. Audio processing happens in DAW (digital audio workstation).
2. External sound card (connected via USB 2.0) with appropriate drivers is used as a sound device.

DAW: Reaper;
Sound Card: Audient id14;
Driver: Asio.

**Problem description:**
Working with audio, sound engineers use VST plugins to process the sound. If add a lot of processing, at some point the sound will start cracking, lagging and be highly distorted. The lack of some resource (which one?)

**Probable solution:**
Changing of one of the sound card parameter: Sample rate (44.1-96 kHZ in my case) or buffer size (16 - 4046 samples in my case).
Increasing buffer size leads to increasing of latency and unloading of... whatever is loaded in this regard.
Reducing of the sample rate also unloads the thing.

**Task manager measurements when cracking happens:**
CPU 50% (7700HQ);
RAM 50% (16Gb) depending on how many programs run in parallel;
Disk 0%.

As you see, there's plenty of "Space" left, but then what limits the amount of processing that can be successfully applied for an audio with a given sample rate and buffer size? Any suggestions of how it can be enhanced?

Comment: I am very open to correction on this, but I believe audio is typically processed on a single high-priority thread. It is my understanding that audio DSP can then not be executed on multiple cores. So, although the CPU may be only be showing 50% usage, have at look at what the usage is like across cores.

Comment: How do you improve processing? Really the only ways are to offload the processing onto a bespoke piece of hardware (look at Universal Audio and their DSP Cards) or get a bigger, faster processor and do your best to vectorise any processing with [AVX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions) (or whichever [SIMD instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) are relevant).

Comment: Your external USB sound card is just an interface for ADC and DAC. No DSP will be done onboard.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It doesn't seem so. I see the boost in used RAM as I started the DAW. Then after it's loaded pushing "play" or adding vst don't have a visible effect on these. (Look at the picture I've just attached). Maybe the limiting thing is the speed of exchange of RAM?

Comment: Then it may be a case that the buffer is too small for your interface. An increase in resources is sadly not going to improve that. To be thorough, it would be worthwhile testing exactly the same settings but with another audio interface, possibly one with an alternative to USB2 e.g. Firewire, Thunderbolt, PCI.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find performance meters in my DAW. According to them, CPU usage is 10%, while so-called **"real time CPU", or "RT CPU" is maxing**. Other performance parameters, like disk read/write, ram usage are loaded at low levels.

I also found that in **"preferences" - "buffer" there's an option to "allow live FX multiprocessing on 8 cores"**. On other forums I read that it helped someone. Though it had no significant effect on my issue.
What I found out is that there're some real-time processing that some VST employs (Ozone VST low end focus). Such single effect can take 80% of your RT CPU.

**The strategy that I'm gonna employ is:**

1. Separate stages "recording" and "mixing". For recording use ASIO with low buffer size to get rid of unwanted latency while using sample rate as high as possible to get a source tracks with good resolution. For mixing - vice versa. + If that's not enough - choosing some default driver, like "Direct Sound" and output from your PC, not from the external sound card (that may to some extend influence the quality of the sound, but still...)
2. Separate stages "Mixing" from "mastering". I.E. while mixing work with multitracks. While mastering work with a single previously mixed track.
3. I'm not an adherent of "freezing" tracks, but if something is sure won't be used at the stage - that may be an option to free some extra resources.